# Dynamically adding boxes to Shiny Dashboard directly

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to add multiple boxes to a shiny interface based on the content of a vector.

Let's start here:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Dynamic Boxes"),

   fluidRow(
     uiOutput("boxes")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$boxes <- renderUI({
    interf <- ""
    for(i in 1:10){
      x = 1:100
      interf <- box(title = paste0("box ", i), 
          renderPlot(plot(x = x, y = x^i)))

    }
    interf
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It only shows the last box. I can't figure out how to combine them together and then pass it to the client side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render Box Dynamically in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51375520/render-box-dynamically-in-shiny)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`box` is from `shinydashboard` package which you haven't loaded (at least in your post). Anyways, you need a list of box elements which your for loop does not create. Here's one way -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(      
  titlePanel("Dynamic Boxes"),      
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("boxes")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {      
  output$boxes <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:10, function(a) {
      x = 1:100
      box(title = paste0("box ", a), renderPlot(plot(x = x, y = x^a)))
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to make this using a shiny modules concept ? can you provide an example here ?